# PostgreSQL exits after being started

Tags: debian, postgresql, debian-jessie

My PostgreSQL 9.5 server on Debian 8 (Jessie) keeps exiting directly after being started via `service postgresql start`:

```
# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fr 2016-12-02 11:02:51 CET; 11min ago
  Process: 2360 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2360 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Dez 05 16:29:24 dev systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Dez 05 16:29:24 dev systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Note the `active (exited)` state. The server is down, e.g. I cannot connect to it via TCP or domain socket, and I can't find any associated processes.

However, when I [start PostgreSQL manually](https://serverfault.com/a/587275/122865) it works:

```
# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/ -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf 

2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-1] DEBUG:  postgres: PostmasterMain: initial environment dump:
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-2] DEBUG:  -----------------------------------------
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-3] DEBUG:     LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-4] DEBUG:     LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-5] DEBUG:     LC_MONETARY=C
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-6] DEBUG:     TERM=xterm-256color
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-7] DEBUG:     LC_NUMERIC=C
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-8] DEBUG:     LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-9] DEBUG:     LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-10] DEBUG:    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-11] DEBUG:    LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-12] DEBUG:    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-13] DEBUG:    LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-14] DEBUG:    LC_TIME=C
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-15] DEBUG:    LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-16] DEBUG:    SHELL=/bin/bash
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-17] DEBUG:    MAIL=/var/mail/postgres
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-18] DEBUG:    LOGNAME=postgres
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-19] DEBUG:    USER=postgres
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-20] DEBUG:    USERNAME=postgres
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-21] DEBUG:    HOME=/var/lib/postgresql
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-22] DEBUG:    SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/ -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-23] DEBUG:    SUDO_USER=root
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-24] DEBUG:    SUDO_UID=0
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-25] DEBUG:    SUDO_GID=0
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-26] DEBUG:    PGLOCALEDIR=/usr/share/locale
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-27] DEBUG:    PGSYSCONFDIR=/etc/postgresql-common
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-28] DEBUG:    LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-29] DEBUG:    LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-30] DEBUG:    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-31] DEBUG:  -----------------------------------------
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-32] DEBUG:  invoking IpcMemoryCreate(size=23887872)
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-33] DEBUG:  mmap(25165824) with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Cannot allocate memory
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-34] DEBUG:  SlruScanDirectory invoking callback on pg_notify/0000
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-35] DEBUG:  removing file "pg_notify/0000"
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-36] DEBUG:  dynamic shared memory system will support 288 segments
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-37] DEBUG:  created dynamic shared memory control segment 1173813643 (2316 bytes)
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-38] DEBUG:  max_safe_fds = 983, usable_fds = 1000, already_open = 7
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-39] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2016-12-05 16:34:32 CET [1593-40] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "/var/log/postgresql".

(server is now up and running and can be connected to)
```

The logs in `/var/log/postgresql` don't contain anything suspicious. Here's the output for a working manual run:

```
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-12-05 16:36:04 CET
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-2] DEBUG:  checkpoint record is at 0/13823548
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-3] DEBUG:  redo record is at 0/13823548; shutdown TRUE
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-4] DEBUG:  next transaction ID: 0/14019; next OID: 35693
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-5] DEBUG:  next MultiXactId: 1; next MultiXactOffset: 0
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-6] DEBUG:  oldest unfrozen transaction ID: 617, in database 1
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-7] DEBUG:  oldest MultiXactId: 1, in database 1
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-8] DEBUG:  commit timestamp Xid oldest/newest: 0/0
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-9] DEBUG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2147484264, limited by database with OID 1
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-10] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is 2147483648, limited by database with OID 1
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-11] DEBUG:  starting up replication slots
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-12] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is 2147483648, limited by database with OID 1
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-13] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-14] DEBUG:  MultiXact member stop limit is now 4294914944 based on MultiXact 1
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-15] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-16] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 3 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-17] DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-18] DEBUG:  exit(0)
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-19] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-20] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1700-21] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1698-41] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1705-1] DEBUG:  removing permanent stats file "pg_stat/db_12381.stat"
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1704-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1704-2] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1705-2] DEBUG:  removing permanent stats file "pg_stat/db_0.stat"
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1704-3] DEBUG:  StartTransaction
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1705-3] DEBUG:  removing permanent stats file "pg_stat/global.stat"
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1704-4] DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children: 
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1704-5] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1704-6] DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       STARTED; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children: 
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1705-4] DEBUG:  received inquiry for database 0
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1705-5] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1705-6] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat"
2016-12-05 16:48:07 CET [1701-1] DEBUG:  checkpointer updated shared memory configuration values
```

In case of an unsuccessful run via `service postgresql start`, no logs are written at all to `/var/log/postgresql`. Similarly, I can't find any PostgreSQL-related messages in `/var/log/messages`.

I've installed PostgreSQL via the official repository:

```
# apt-cache policy postgresql-9.5
postgresql-9.5:
  Installed: 9.5.5-1.pgdg80+1
  Candidate: 9.5.5-1.pgdg80+1
  Version table:
 *** 9.5.5-1.pgdg80+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

All of this is on a VirtualBox VM.

## Update 1

The systemd unit seems to belong to the `postgresql-common` package:

```
# find /lib/systemd -iname "*postgres*"
/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service
/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator

# dpkg -S postgresql.service
postgresql-common: /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service

# dpkg -S postgresql@.service
postgresql-common: /lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service

# dpkg -S postgresql-generator
postgresql-common: /lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator
```

Here's their content:

**`/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`**

```
# systemd service for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on the system. This
# service is actually a systemd target, but we are using a service since
# targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**`/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service`**

```
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# @: use "postgresql@%i" as process name
ExecStart=@/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/var/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-900
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**`/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator`**

```
#!/bin/sh

# This systemd generator creates dependency symlinks that make all PostgreSQL
# clusters with "auto" in their start.conf file be started/stopped/reloaded
# when postgresql.service is started/stopped/reloaded.

set -eu

gendir="$1"
wantdir="$1/postgresql.service.wants"
pgservice="/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service"

mkdir -p "$wantdir"

for conf in /etc/postgresql/*/*/postgresql.conf; do
    test -e "$conf" || continue
    dir="${conf%/*}"

    # evaluate start.conf
    if [ -e "$dir/start.conf" ]; then
        start=$(sed 's/#.*$//; /^[[:space:]]*$/d; s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//' "$dir/start.conf")
    else
        start=auto
    fi
    [ "$start" = "auto" ] || continue

    verdir="${dir%/*}"
    version="${verdir##*/}"
    cluster="${dir##*/}"
    ln -s "$pgservice" "$wantdir/postgresql@$version-$cluster.service"
done

exit 0
```

`postgresql-common` was installed from the official PostgreSQL repository as a dependency of the `postgresql-9.5` package:

```
# apt-cache policy postgresql-common
postgresql-common:
  Installed: 177.pgdg80+1
  Candidate: 177.pgdg80+1
  Version table:
 *** 177.pgdg80+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     165+deb8u1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

## Update 2

As requested, here's the output of `strace -f service postgresql start` [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bYwjWeRv) (due to its size).

Comment: Do `netstat -punta` after starting it manually, is `postgres` listening on any port?

Comment: @Alex When I start PostgreSQL manually it listens and accepts connections via TCP (port 5432) and domain socket (`/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`). When I start it via `service` none of that works.

Comment: You could give `strace` a try:

Comment: `strace -f service postgresql start`

Comment: @OliverRahner: Thanks for the idea, i've updated my answer with the output of `strace`.

Comment: Have you tried running `systemctl daemon-reload`? It looks like the generator may have to be run before you can start the service.

Comment: @TimLamballais Thanks for your input! Unfortunately, running `systemctl daemon-reload` before `service postgresql restart` did not change anything. The service is marked as `active (exited)` as before.

Comment: Does it work if you run `systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main.service` ?

Comment: @MatthewIfe It does! Please post that as an answer. If you can also explain why `systemctl start postgresql` doesn't work or what I need to do to make it work then even better ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theres a couple of things going on here. If you call a systemd service with an `@` in it, its a signal to start an instance rather than main service. Putting `@9.5-main` is telling it the instance parameters to use.

The postgres service file you are seeing is nothing more than a placeholder. There is a directory on the system (its normally somewhere in `/run`) called `postgresql.wants.d` which the systemd will look for when `postgresql.service` is started.

Anything in that directory will be started along with it as `postgresql.service` is told it wants it.

That directory is filled through a shell script generator file as everything in `/run` is a tmpfs. Thats the shell script you quoted above.

If I had to hazard a guess whats going on there via the logic of the shell script, you probably have got the file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/start.conf` set to `manual`.

This means the generator skips over it and the `postgresql.wants.d` never gets added with that instance name.

According to the script logic simply removing it has the right affect of making it auto.

You can also set it to `auto` and do a `daemon-reload` to regenerate the necessary config.

Comment: Thanks, this has already clarified a lot! However, my `/etc/postgresql/9.5./main/start.conf` already says `auto`. If I manually execute `/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator 9.5-main` from within `/run/systemd/generator/postgresql.service.wants` then the necessary link gets created and everything works after I `systemctl restart postgresl` (although `systemctl status postgresql` still says `active (exited)`). However, after a reboot the `wants` link is not created automatically, and `systemctl daemon-reload` doesn't re-create it either. Any ideas?

Comment: You could possibly try copying the generator to  `/etc/systemd/system-generators/` and seeing if it works from that path on reboot.

Something might be wrong with the shellscript at boot time (maybe a filesystem isn't mounted?). You'd have to alter the shellscript to get it to be more verbose and store the data somewhere to see what gets executed from within it.

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload` does run the generator, I must have missed that in my previous comment.  However I can't get the generator to run at boot-time, so as a hacky workaround I'm now running `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart postgresql` after booting via a Vagrant provision script. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As of 26 May 2017, the issue still exists on Debian 8 (as far as I can see): PostgreSQL fails to start on boot.

The solution for the time being is to issue:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart postgresql
```

manually on boot and everything should be all right. Thanks to Florian Brucker for pointing this out above.

The bug is apparently in systemd and, hopefully, should be rectified soon.

Comment: Had this issue with ubuntu 20 and postgres 12.6 now. Can this still be the same bug or can this workaround address also other issues? No error log, nothing, I had no idea why the service was not starting.

Comment: @jan check `systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service`

Comment: This `systemctl` combo helped me on Ubuntu 20.04 with Postgres 14 that worked fine for a couple of restarts over a few days and then suddenly went on strike today. I had an error in `postgresql.conf` that wasn't reported, perhaps because I also changed the logging config, but no log appeared on custom location either (which worked when started properly). Even after reverting the config, the restart didn't help, but after both commands from above, it did. Thank you. But I'm still completely puzzled why no log appeared anywhere.