# postgresql psql : could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, installation

First I want to start by saying the most relevant answer was [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/818838/postgresql-exits-after-being-started). When I try to run the following here's what I get:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I can also confirm that the server starts up and quits by running the first command below. The second command below confirms that the server started but immediately exited,

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-09-25 18:37:32 EDT; 11min ago
  Process: 8459 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8459 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 25 18:37:32 atas-250-557 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Sep 25 18:37:32 atas-250-557 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

An answer that seems promising:

- [postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/server-start.html) telling me to start my server in `/usr/local/pgsql/data` but I DON'T EVEN HAVE the dir `/usr/local/pgsql`. This leads me to believe that in my installations and deletions something was not reinstalled.
- I have installed

  - `sudo apt-get install postgresql`
  - `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common`
  - `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client`
  - PostgreSQL-9.6.5 for Ubuntu 16.04 via the installer (but this may be redundant).

Lastly, the uninstaller found in `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6` doesn't even remove everything from my system the way it should. I'm left with [a the window of the leftover files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br1Lp.png) after uninstalling. If you could help me fix the `could not connect to server` issue at the top that would be preferred. Last resort I would be willing to wipe everything clean, but haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PostgreSQL-9.6.5 for Ubuntu 16.04 via the installer (but this may be redundant)

This isn't redundant, you've installed two different versions of Postgres in two different locations. On a package management system like Ubuntu (and most flavors of Linux) you should *only* use the version of software found int he package manager. You likely used the installer off their website which installed Postgres either in `/opt/` or `/usr/local/` and changed your systemd target files to point to that installation. Meanwhile your client comes from the package manager and is expecting the UNIX domain socket it connects to in `/var/run`.

If this is a throw away virtual machine, wipe it, reinstall and only install Postgres via `apt-get`. If not, see if you can uninstall the package you downloaded and reinstall the other packages via `apt-get` (which will hopefully fix your systemd target files to point to the right location).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a virtual machine. I'll see what I can do to uninstall via the uninstaller

Answer (score 0):

I just ran on my Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo reboot
```

After OS restarted the problem was gone.